# Вычисление двойного интеграла

Tags: python, алгоритм, изображения

Мне нужно вычислить двойной интеграл с помощью dblquad.

У меня ругается вот так:
IntegrationWarning: The maximum number of subdivisions (50) has been achieved.
If increasing the limit yields no improvement it is advised to analyze
the integrand in order to determine the difficulties.  If the position of a
local difficulty can be determined (singularity, discontinuity) one will
probably gain from splitting up the interval and calling the integrator
on the subranges.  Perhaps a special-purpose integrator should be used.

У меня pix[i,j][0] массив из значений пикселей. n[i]= массив из чисел от 1 до 600 m[j] = 1 до 462

```
C = [[0] * width for i in range(height)]
for i in range(len(n)):
    for j in range(len(m)):
        C[i][j] = dblquad(lambda x, y: pix[i, j][0] * math.sin(math.pi*x*n[i]/width)*math.sin(math.pi*y*m[j]/height)*math.sin(math.pi*x*n[i]/width)*math.sin(math.pi*y*m[j]/height), 0, height, lambda x: 0, lambda x: width)
```

Я просто пытаюсь реализовывать разные методы устранения артефактов\шумов на изображении. Решил попробовать разложить по синусам и косинусам.

Answer (score 0):

При высоких частотах синусоида сильно осциллирует, поэтому адаптивный алгоритм выбора делителя интервала на отрезки за 50 итераций не сходится.

Исходный текст [`dblquad`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.7.1/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py#L530-L602) показывает, что эта функция внутри себя вызывает [`nquad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.nquad.html#scipy.integrate.nquad). В вашем случае вызов сводится к `nquad(ваша_функция, [[0,width], [0,height]], opts={"epsabs": 1.49e-8, "epsrel": 1.49e-8})`

Число итераций управляется опцией `limit`. Добавьте в параметр `opts` пару `"limit": 100` или любое другое число.

Но на самом деле я бы рекомендовал вам освоить `numpy` и быстрое двумерное преобразование Фурье [`numpy.fft.fft2`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft2.html). После этого вы сможете легко и непринуждённо раскладывать изображения на двумерные гармоники специализированным методом [`rfft2`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft2.html) для вещественно значных функций.